# Unable to run console on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app on a Heroku server, but for some reason I can neither start my app nor `run console`. When I try to execute `heroku run console`, I get the following:

```
MacBook:threexortwo lander$ heroku run console
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.1  
Rubber[ERROR]: Unable to read rubber configuration from /app/config/rubber/rubber.yml  
(erb):301:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `rubber_env' for main:Object (NameError)  
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:753:in `eval'  
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/erb.rb:753:in `result'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/environment.rb:39:in `read_config'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/environment.rb:30:in `block in initialize'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/environment.rb:30:in `each'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/environment.rb:30:in `initialize'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/configuration.rb:37:in `new'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/configuration.rb:37:in `initialize'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/configuration.rb:14:in `new'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/configuration.rb:14:in `get_configuration'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/configuration.rb:22:in `rubber_env'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber.rb:53:in `config'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber.rb:31:in `initialize'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rubber-2.1.2/lib/rubber/railtie.rb:9:in `block in <class:Railtie>'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:67:in `inherited'  
    from /app/config/application.rb:13:in `<module:Threexortwo>'  
    from /app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'  
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'  
    from script/rails:6:in `require'  
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Previously, I was playing with an Amazon EC2 server, and was using `rubber`. Before doing anything with `rubber`, I created a backup (pretty much just zipped the project), then afterwards deleted the `vulcanized` version, restored the old one, and uninstalled `rubber. When I run my server app locally, I don't encounter this issue, and I only get it when messing with Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like rubber is still in your gemfile. Heroku reads in your gemfile and installs all of the gems listed.

Try removing it.

Comment: That's what I had thought as well, but it's actually not... Here's my gemfile: http://pastebin.com/bK5ADwXL

Comment: Upon further review, it appears as though my git repo had never actually committed... So that was, in fact, the error. Just needed a push. Thanks!